# jQuery add 7 days to date (input and output type text)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do a simple page that takes a date (input type TEXT), and once the date is entered, another field will add 7 days to the input and display the date (+7 days) in a text input. My knowledge of jQuery is limited so I may have a small bug...

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Date Plus 7 Days</title> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    function DateFromString(str){ 
        str = str.split(/\D+/);
        str = new Date(str[2],str[0]-1,(parseInt(str[1])+7));
        return MMDDYYYY(str);
    }
    function MMDDYYYY(str) {
        var ndateArr = str.toString().split(' ');
        var Months = 'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec';
        return (parseInt(Months.indexOf(ndateArr[1])/4)+1)+'/'+ndateArr[2]+'/'+ndateArr[3];
    }

    function Add7Days() {
        var date = $('#start_date').val();
        var ndate = DateFromString(date);
        return ndate;
    }

    $('#start_date').change(function(){
        $('#end_date') = Add7Days();
    })

});

</script> 
</head> 
<body> 

Start Date
<input type="text" id="start_date" value=''> 
<br>
End date
<input type="text" id="end_date" value=''> 

</body> 
</html>
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You're leaving it up to the user to input the date in the format you expect.  You should never trust the user. Since you're already leveraging jQuery take a look at the jQuery UI datepicker.  This will give you a calendar, and much more reliable date entry values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you've attempted to assign an object to `$('#end_date')`. jQuery deals with this in a different way by altering the value of the input box by leveraging `.val('value-here')`

Try this:

```
$('#start_date').change(function(){
    $('#end_date').val(Add7Days());
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zydZ2/

Also, Moment.JS is great for parsing and manipulating dates, I'd strongly recommend checking that out: http://momentjs.com/

Hope this helps!

Comment: The result of `$()` is not a function; it's an object

Comment: @Ian apologies, you're 100% correct. Updated to reflect this.

Comment: @KyleMuir No big deal, just didn't want to confuse the OP and others :)

Comment: This has a problem in different browsers. ndateArr[3] in IE returns year ie. 2014 where as FF and chrome returns time in that array index. So someone post correct answer.

Comment: momentjs rocks! Thanks for recommending momentjs. I was just getting it in sight of me today when searching for solution regarding date manipulation but did not pay attention. Now, I looked at this and solved my date manipulation problems like a charm within minutes.

Answer (score 8):

functionally to add 7days to an existing date can be achieved by using

```
var today_date = new Date()
alert(today_date)
today_date.setDate(today_date.getDate() + 7)
alert(today_date)
```

this will add seven days to an existing date if its 31 than it will make it 7th of next month

hope this help

Comment: But it increases month as well

Answer (score 2):

Your may using JQuery & JqueryUI datepicker featured to did it.

```
    $('#start_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        minDate: 0,

    });
    $("#end_date").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        minDate:  7,

    });

    var _dt = new Date();
    var _dt = _dt.setDate(_dt.getDate());       
    $("#start_date").datepicker("setDate","mm/dd/yy", _dt);
    $("#end_date").datepicker("setDate", "mm/dd/yy", _dt);
```

you may refer this http://jsfiddle.net/o9grLdf0/12/

min = 0 for input startdate = today date
and 
min = 7 mean today + 7 day for enddate

Comment: please give some explanation,that how this code solves the problem of user.

Answer (score 0):

```
function listDatesBetweenTwoDates(S_dateA, S_dateB) {
    var O_dateA = moment(S_dateA).add(1, 'd');
    var O_dateB = moment(S_dateB).add(1, 'd');
    var O_itr = moment.twix(O_dateA, O_dateB).iterate("days");
    var A_range = [];
    while (O_itr.hasNext()) {
        A_range.push(O_itr.next().toDate())
    }
    return A_range;
}
```